# Write a Python program that takes the user's name as input and displays it

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
name = input('Enter your name: ')
print(name[0])
print(name[1])
print(name[2])
print(name[3])
print(name[4])
print(name[5])
print(name[6])
print(name[7])
print(name[8])
print(name[9])
print(name[10])
print(name[11])
print(name[12])
print(name[12])
print(name[13])
```

The problem is that when I run this program and if the letters are less than 13 it gives an error, how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through strings in Python, using a standard `for` loop. Doing so iterates through each character of the string.

Consider the following:

```
name = input('Enter your name: ')
for char in name:
    print(char)
```

This makes no assumption as to the length of the input.

Answer (score 1):

Use for loop!

```
for i in name:
  print(i + "\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have not learnt loops and still want to print your name one char each line, you can do something like this.

```
name = input('Enter your name: ')
print (*name,sep='\n')
```

The `*name` will send the data to print statement one char at a time. The `sep='\n` will ensure that the separator is a new line. That way each character will get printed on a new line.

Here's a sample output of the above program.

```
Enter your name: Shivansh Sahu
S
h
i
v
a
n
s
h
 
S
a
h
u
```

Congrats on getting started with Python programming. Hope you do well. Good luck and don't hesitate to ask questions. We are here to help you learn.